# set read and write permissions to folder and all its parent directories

Tags: permissions, directory

I need to set read and write permissions for `root` user to directory `subfolderN` and all its parent folders till `root`.

I can do it by hands:

```
$ sudo chmod +rx /root/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolderN
$ sudo chmod +rx /root/subfolder1/subfolder2
$ sudo chmod +rx /root/subfolder1
$ sudo chmod +rx /root
```

But if `N` is big I am tired. How to do automatically by one command?

Comment: You should really **not** make `/root` world readable.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This can be done easily in the shell, starting in the subdir and moving upwards:

```
f=/root/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolderN
while [[ $f != / ]]; do chmod +rx "$f"; f=$(dirname "$f"); done;
```

This starts with whatever file/directory you set f too, and works on every parent directory, until it encounters "/" (or whatever you set the string in the condition of the loop to). It does not chmod "/". Make sure both `f` and the directory in the condition of the loop are absolute paths.

Comment: Nice, I knew I was complicating things needlessly with Perl.

Comment: But what if `f` is a relative path, and I want to stop at what it is relative to instead of `/`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks.   If `$f` is `foo/bar`, will `$f` ever change to `.`? Yes `dirname` does it. Thanks

Comment: @Tim convert relative path to absolute path before storing in f using command "f=\`readlink -f <relative_path>\`"

Comment: Remember to use absolute path. I used short link path and had a lot problems. Finally get it back to normal.

Comment: I had to remove the quotation marks to make it work for my case: `f=/root/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolderN; while [[ $f != / ]]; do chmod +x $f; f=$(dirname $f); done;`

Answer (score 8):

With `csh`, `tcsh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `bash`, `fish` or `yash -o braceexpand`:

```
sudo chmod +rx /root{,/subfolder1{,/subfolder2{,/subfolderN}}}
```

With `zsh`:

```
f=/root/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolderN
until [[ $f = / ]] {chmod +rx $f; f=$f:h;}
```

Or you could define a glob qualifier function like:

```
explode() {
  reply=()
  until [[ $REPLY = [./] ]] {
    reply+=$REPLY
    REPLY=$REPLY:h
  }
}
```

To be used for instance as:

```
$ echo chmod +rx subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolderN(+explode)
chmod +rx subfolder1 subfolder1/subfolder2 subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolderN
```

Note that `chmod +rx` is affected by the umask. If your `umask` doesn't  include `007`, it would  make the `/root` directory world-readable and accessible which is a bad idea. `/root` is typically for the super-user's private things, it's a bad idea to expose it.

Comment: Could you explain what the leading `,` in `{,/subfolder}` does?

Comment: It creates an alternation where the first string is empty and the second is `/subfolder`; so `/root{,/subfolder}` produces `/root` and `/root/subfolder`

Comment: Notably this is **not** portable to POSIX `sh`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but is better than you **don't take the recursive lightly**. That said, read the actual answer:

Umm... why not just use recursive.

```
sudo chmod -R +rx /root
```

Or if you don't like it, you can give `chmod` several directories:

```
sudo chamod +rx /root /root/subfolder1 /root/subfolder1/subfolder2 /root/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolderN
```

Comment: That's not nearly the same operation, though.  `chmod -R /root` changes *everything* under `/root` — including regular files and all directories. The question is about changing one chain of directories only.

Comment: @200_success but that's not the only answer ;)

Comment: The question is not about recursion, but how to set permissions on a chain of parent folders to allow selective access to a subfolder. Saying that it's not the only answer is like saying driving a bus through your wall is another way to make a door.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do something slightly more complex like:

```
echo "/root/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolderN" | 
 perl -anF'/' -e 'while($#F>0){@b=join("/",@F);`chmod +rx @b`; pop @F}'
```

To see what this will do, replace the `chmod` call with print:

```
$ echo "/root/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolderN" | 
 perl -alnF'/' -e 'while($#F>0){@b=join("/",@F);print "chmod +rx @b"; pop @F}' 
chmod +rx /root/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolderN
chmod +rx /root/subfolder1/subfolder2
chmod +rx /root/subfolder1
chmod +rx /root
```