# How do I open access (+x) to a directory behind symlinks in one move?

Tags: permissions, filesystems

For example, to open access to `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/`, the following need to be done:

```
chmod  a+x /sys/bus/
chmod  a+x /sys/bus/usb/
chmod  a+x /sys/bus/usb/devices/
# files in "devices" are symlinks
chmod a+x /sys/devices
chmod a+x /sys/devices/pci0000:00/
chmod a+x /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0
chmod a+x /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1
chmod a+x /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1
```

How do I do that in one move? I want to do something like

```
chgrp_alt usb -R /sys/bus/usb/devices/*
chmod_alt g+rX -R /sys/bus/usb/devices/*
```

Related (simpler) quesiton: [set read and write permissions to folder and all its parent directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90590/set-read-and-write-permissions-to-folder-and-all-its-parent-directories)

Comment: Use a find and follow the symlinks option?

Comment: How will `find` find, for example, `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/` if the symlink goes deeper?